# SQL Add row values and rank results based on this

Tags: mysql, sql

Hard one to explain, I have a table with many values in one column where many repeat throughout the table, at the moment I am only chosing the rows where these values appear more than 3 times.

What I now need to do is look at these rows add the values of a seperate column in each row and then order the results based on these.

Forexample, if skybox appears more than 3 times, then look at the column clicks on each row and add them, then rank that result based on if it has more or less than the others.

Example

```
Skybox appears 4 times and has Clicks values 12,13,1,19
test appears 3 times and has Clicks values 23,42,1,43
Test should rank higher in the results as it has more clicks when added
```

Current query

```
SELECT * FROM `data` GROUP BY SearchQuery HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please add the expected result (and its relation to the input as shown in your example).

Comment: the expected result would be that in the output of results test would appear before skybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select name, sum(clicks)
from t
group by name
having count(*) >= 3
order by sum(clicks) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
  SearchQuery, count(*), group_concat(`clicks`) 
FROM data
GROUP BY SearchQuery
HAVING count(*) > 3
ORDER BY sum(`clicks`) desc
```